# Convert vector to circular space with different median

Tags: matlab

I have a vector of 10 random numbers from 1 to 11 (median of the vector 1:11 is 6).

```
min = 1;
max = 11;
nVector = 10;
VectorRand = randi([min max],1,nVector);
```

I would like to convert the values in `VectorRand` to a circular array of 11 values, but with a different median. For example, median 2:

```
-5(8) -4(9) -3(10) -2(11) -1(1) 0(2) +1(3) +2(4) +3(5) +4(6) +5(7)
Result: 8 9 10 11 1 - 2 - 3 4 5 6 7
```

in the case of VectorRand = [1 3 8 4 6 8 5 2 6 8 10]
    Result: -1 1 -5 2 4 -5 3 0 4 -5 -3

where the median (2 in this case) becomes zero and all the other values are translated in terms of distance from the median (e.g. 8=-5, 9=-4 10=-3 and so on).

Comment: How do you get `2` as a median for `VectorRand`? What is a circular array? Which distance do you use? Where do you get your mapping `8-->-5 , 9-->-4 ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The description is confusing, but here's my guess as to what you want:

```
>> % Set parameters
>> minVal = 1;
>> maxVal = 11;
>> newMedian = 2;
>> % Determine mapping
>> currMedian = median(minVal:maxVal);
>> map = circshift((minVal:maxVal) - currMedian, [0 newMedian - currMedian]);
```

This is shifting the range of values so that the median is 0 (this will eventually give you the distances from the target median), and then rotating it so the target median is at the center value of the ordering of values.  Now, with the mapping built, you can map your vector to this new circulant ring:

```
>> VectorRand = [1 3 8 4 6 8 5 2 6 8 10];
>> Result = map(VectorRand)
Result =
    -1     1    -5     2     4    -5     3     0     4    -5    -3
```

Comment: what is "newMedian" in your script? I cannot replicate your result

Comment: Sorry, I had listed this as "newMiddleValue" in my script (I find the use of the term median strange here).  I've edited the answer, and it should work now.

Comment: No Result is still different.

Comment: map = [-5    -4    -3    -2    -1     0     1     2     3     4     5]
Result = [  -5    -3     2    -2     0     2    -1    -4     0     2     4]

Comment: Yes, sorry, I just realized it's the circshift call that's going to give you a different result.  Edited; try one more time.

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you very much! It was tricky to explain but I am happy somebody managed to solve it ;-)

Comment: No problem!  Sorry for the confusion.  I made one last edit replacing that 1 with a 0 in the circshift call.  It doesn't change the result but it is more technically correct (the 1 tells it to shift the rows by 1, but there is only 1 row so it has no effect).